# Cannot install graphics driver via Additional Drivers GUI

Tags: nvidia, additional-drivers

When I try to install the Nvidia graphics driver via `Additional Drivers` GUI on Ubuntu 22.04, I get the following errors while applying changes. Also, the font sizes are super large.

[image]

I will appreciate any ideas for fixing the issue.

Comment: Try a driver without the "-open" in the name.

Comment: @ubfan1 Thanks. I solved it differently. see my answer

Answer (score 1):

When I also tried to install nvidia drivers via command line then I realized that I had broken package issues which was difficult to solve using apt broken install. Then I tried aptitude package manager: `sudo aptitude install nvidia-driver-525` and tried to follow their suggestions. Ultimately i had to downgrade one package and installation completed successfully. Then after reboot the font sizes are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a process to install the recommended drivers with terminal.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```